How to calculate this limit:$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac1h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2}(nh)}{n^2}$
It is a question appeared in the Mathematical Analysis III's final examination of Nankai University
How to calculate this limit?
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac1h\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^{2}(nh)}{n^2}$$

That's the whole question, without anything else
I have no idea how to deal with it, I have tried that let $\frac{\sin^2(nh)}{n^2}$ be $\frac{1-\cos(2nh)}{2n^2}$ but then I cannot get anything.
Thanks a lot for your idea!

This question has been discussed before here at MSE. For example, here
